# How to query a table while comparing column values of two different rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a single table `foo`, with relevant columns `flag`, `date` and `username`.

I am struggling to come up with a PostgreSQL query that does the following:

Select all rows where...

- `date` is later than a specific date
- and `flag = 0`
- and there is NO other row of a later `date` and with `flag = 1` for the same user

...grouped by `username`.

The problem is very much the third requirement in the list above. I have tried building the query using subqueries with `EXCEPT`, `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, `WITH` and `LATERAL`, but I always run into a dead end when the dates of the subqueries must be compared to each other and I cannot reference them.

Is this possible within a single SQL statement?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your current query would also help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a lot like `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where date > ? and flag = 0 and
     not exists (select 1
                 from t t2
                 where t2.username = t.username and t2.flag = 1 and t2.date > t.date
                );
```

If you just want user names meeting the condition, conditional aggregation should suffice:

```
select username
from t
where date > ?
group by username
having min(case when flag = 0 then date end) < max(case when flag = 1 then date end);
```

This is saying that the last `flag = 1` date is later than the earliest `flag = 0`.

Comment: Thank you, this looks very promising! Could you explain what the `having` line in your second example does? I don't understand how the `min/max` functions work in combination with `case`.

Comment: @Hatch . . . I would suggest that you try `min(case . . .)` and `max(case . . .)` in some queries on your data (in the `select`), so you will see what happens.